# can't run ionic app in remote device because of error cat proc cpuinfo

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 4 app which I can even build successfully
my only problem is I can't run it on my remote device

I am using the command "ionic Cordova run android --device" plus  --verbose now because of this error
I am getting

```
"Running command: C:\Users\z00421mt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s HYF0219105012925 shell cat /proc/cpuinfo"
```

And then

```
"Command finished with error code 3221226356: C:\Users\z00421mt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
-s,HYF0219105012925,shell,cat,/proc/cpuinfo Failed to execute shell command "cat,/proc/cpuinfo"" on device: Error: C:\Users\z00421mt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 3221226356 CordovaError: Failed to execute shell command "cat,/proc/cpuinfo"" on device: Error: C:\Users\z00421mt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 3221226356"
```

Can't really find the explanation for this error codes in specific
What should I do?
the ADB list commands works and does show my device
my device has the developer mode activated and the USB debugger activated as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I found was downloading https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r25.0.1-windows.zip